# DB2: Sql to find specific text within column names

Tags: sql, select, db2, information-schema

Need some help with SQL in DB2.

The schema SRC_TEST_PRD has hundreds of tables.  I want the SQL to return :

1. the tablename
2. and the column name for all of those where the column name is LIKE 'DESC'.

Answer (score 1):

In DB2, you can query [catalog view `syscat.columns`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html):

```
select tabname, colname
from syscat.columns
where tabschema = 'SRC_TEST_PRD' and colname like '%DESC%'
```